# Is there an efficient way to join two tables?

Tags: sql

I have a table that stores details of relationships between pairs of users:

```
{user1, user2}
```

and a table about how users review a service:

```
{user, review}
```

I'd like a table that combines this:

```
{user1, user1_review, user2, user2_review}
```

I have done this on test data by 1) creating a product of the review with an alias of itself to give:

```
user1, review1, user2, review2
1, good, 2, poor
1, good, 3, great
2, poor, 1, good
2, poor, 3, great
3, great, 1, good
3, great, 2, poor
```

and then 2) joining this with the user relationships table to end up with a table that shows just those pairs of users who have a relationship, along with what they thought about the service.

This works perfectly but I can't get it to scale. The actual review table is 700MB as a text file and I run out of application memory when running the query to create the product, most of which will be removed in stage 2 anyway.

Is there any other way I can organise this to achieve what I want?

Comment: You say 700MB as a text file, but is the data stored in a real dbms table now? Table definitions, any indexes etc?

Comment: what database you are using? are there any indexes?

Comment: Using the sqldf package in R. No indexes just plain text stored in CSV format.

Comment: Ummm... why not join stage 2, then? Intermediary tables rarely help with query performance. You generally want to filter out as much irrelevant data as possible, as soon as possible.

Comment: What RDBMS is this in? It shouldn't be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a cross-product of an enormous table — it runs horribly slowly if the optimizer doesn't work out how to avoid doing what you tell it to do.

You need to join the relationship table with two aliases of the reviews table:

```
SELECT user1, r1.review AS user1_review, user2, r2.review AS user2_review
  FROM relationship AS r0
  JOIN review AS r1 ON r0.user1 = r1.user
  JOIN review AS r2 ON r0.user2 = r2.user
```

Do make sure you've got appropriate indexes in place.  That would be on the User column of the Review table and possibly indexes with each of the User columns in the Relationship table as the leading column (you probably have a unique index on the pair of columns — say (`user1`, `user2`) in that order; you then need an index on `user2` as well).

And you say ["Plain text stored in 700 MiB CSV format"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496045/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-join-two-tables/32496196#comment52852017_32496045) — forget about performance; there isn't a performant way of processing that short of storing it in a regular indexed table.  Tables are created to give you performance.  CSV files do not provide performance as an option.

Comment: If this is all user relationships and reviews being queried then the indexes may not be beneficial of course, depending on the RDBMS.

Comment: Yes; indexing is DBMS-specific.  I regard that as covered under 'appropriate indexes'.  If a specific index won't be used by the DBMS, it isn't appropriate.